# Windows mobile 6 self updating app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, auto-update, windows-mobile-6

Is it possible to create an application for windows mobile 6 that can either periodically or on demand update itself to the latest version?
I was thinking of maybe creating a project containing 2 solutions, the first one runs on execution and overwrites the second solutions executable with that of one on an ftp server, then starts the second solution...

Do you think this will work or do you have any thoughts on a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446487.aspx ; even better is this project that I have implemented and works quite well https://github.com/seboslaw/wmautoupdate , those two will get you going in the right direction.